# Apache Mahout. Limit or Offset for recommendations

Tags: java, apache, pagination, mahout, recommendation-engine

I wanted to implement a pagination with mahout(specfying, offset and max result) how do I achieve that with Mahout? so let's say I have this code that generates recommendations

```
 File ratingsFile = new File("audio-dummy-bool.csv");                        
 DataModel model = new FileDataModel(ratingsFile);

    CachingRecommender cachingRecommender2 = new CachingRecommender(new SlopeOneRecommender(model));





// for all users
for (LongPrimitiveIterator it = model.getUserIDs(); it.hasNext();){
    long userId = it.nextLong();

    // get the recommendations for the user
    List<RecommendedItem> recommendations = cachingRecommender.recommend(userId, 10);

    // if empty write something
    if (recommendations.size() == 0){
        System.out.print("User ");
        System.out.print(userId);
        System.out.println(": no recommendations");
    }

    // print the list of recommendations for each 
    for (RecommendedItem recommendedItem : recommendations) {
        System.out.print("User ");
        System.out.print(userId);
        System.out.print(": ");
        System.out.println(recommendedItem);
    }
}
```

I wanted to implement a pagination for this because the recommendation might generate a thousand results for the user, which whill cost a lot in memory. is there anyway I can specify the max result and offset for generation recommendations in mahout?

Comment: When you say `recommend(userId, 10)` you are telling the recommender to try and generate 10 recommendations to the `user`. Depending on your the intricacies of your data you might get less or none, but not more than 10

Answer (score 2):

You want to 'page' through the results? No there is no way to do that. You can request N, store and serve results from those, and then go back and ask for 2N if needed, etc. But ther is no 'offset'.

Comment: is it better to use a CSV file for storing ratings and audio tags? or it is better to use a database when getting/creating recommendations?

Comment: For Mahout it doesn't matter. You are going to have to read them into memory anyway to make it run fast. whether it came from a file or DB doesn't matter much.

Comment: Is there anyway I can reload the db model or file model? so that I can fetch a live updates(like when a user liked a video/song/books few seconds ago?

Comment: Yes. If you are working with a database, wrap your DataModel inside a ReloadFromJDBCDataModel and use the #refresh method of your recommender. It´s also possible to update from a file (look for JavaDoc --> FileDataModel)